# Extending the maximum length of MATLAB function names

Tags: function, matlab

I have a written a MATLAB program that creates custom MATLAB functions on the fly and launches them in other MATLAB instances using `unix` command. I use this program for automatizing fMRI neuroimaging analyses (using SPM8 for MATLAB), and everything works fine. However, MATLAB imposes a function name length maximum of 63 characters (`namelengthmax`). As I need to save two different timestamps in each function name together with the name of the function that created it (I have several different functions that create these new functions that are used for multithreaded fMRI analysis), 63 characters is quite limiting for filenames like:

`atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15.m`

In this example `atf` means 'analysis thread function' (to separate it from other files with similar filenames), the first timestamp identifies the run (a global timestamp, it this case 5th of July 2012 at 18:01:02), then there's a string `specify_1st_level` that identifies the function (in this case `specify_1st_level.m`) that created this new 'analysis thread function', and then the second time stamp identifies this specific new 'analysis thread function' from other new 'analysis thread functions' created to be run in other threads (and for different analysis subjects, or for different analyses) and that are run simultaneously.

**My problem is the character limit of 63 characters for function names.**

I'm aware that I could write my timestamps without underscores (`_`), or compress them, and I can make my function names shorter (eg. `specify_1st_level.m` -> `sp1st.m`), and also I could divide my functions created on the fly in different subfolders also created on the fly named eg. with global timestamps. **Edit:** Or I could even create a hash of the entire function name and use the hash as a function name instead of the human-readable string presented above.

However, I plan to add more data in the names of 'analysis thread functions' (one or more hash values of different analysis parameter sets used in this run to identify identical analyses of different times). If possible, I would like to keep it nice and simple (human-readable function names help in debugging of 'analysis thread functions' created on the fly).

**So, is there any way to extend** `namelengthmax` **?** I'm running MATLAB R2012a in Linux.  I'm also happy to hear any other ways to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Matlab sets this as a hard coded thing.  You can look at `namelengthmax` as that is what sets the max.  I doubt that it can be changed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my own question: After thinking it some more, I found a way to embed as much information as I want into a MATLAB function name and still keep it readable for humans. First, I'll compute SHA1 hash of my function filename: SHA1 hash of `atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15.m` is `E545831A 0002C73B CA095F11 25FC5C51 35B82451` (here presented with spaces for clarity).

Then my function name will be `[ 'atf_', sha1hashString, '.m' ]`, for this example that'll be `atf_E545831A0002C73BCA095F1125FC5C5135B82451.m`, so the function name length will be 44 characters, that's no problem at all. This solves the limitation of 63 characters, but I also need a way to be able to find my functions using regular bash commands.

So I'll create a copy of that function file, concatenating the hash to the end of the original function name, so it becames `atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15_E545831A0002C73BCA095F1125FC5C5135B82451.m`. Then I can find the correct function easily in bash using `ls` or `find` (for debugging purposes), check the hash from the end of the filename and set breakpoint in MATLAB debugger in the function that will be called from MATLAB (eg. `atf_E545831A0002C73BCA095F1125FC5C5135B82451.m`) and use MATLAB debugger without problems.

This is the most practical solution I can think of and it makes possible to add hashes of analysis parameter sets into the function name too: I'll just compute the SHA1 hash of the analysis parameter set (let's assume that the SHA1 hash of the parameter set is `A9993E36 4706816A BA3E2571 7850C26C 9CD0D89D`, and concatenated with original function name it'll be `atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15_A9993E364706816ABA3E25717850C26C9CD0D89D.m`. Then I'll compute a new SHA1 hash of this original function name extended with the SHA1 hash of the analysis parameter sets: SHA1 hash of `atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15_A9993E364706816ABA3E25717850C26C9CD0D89D.m` is `A81F0083 38868103 F1A0DB69 010279D5 5DB3751E`. Then I'll create two identical functions, one for MATLAB and one for my debugging purposes, and they will be named `atf_A81F008338868103F1A0DB69010279D55DB3751E.m` and `atf_2012_07_05_18_01_02_specify_1st_level_2012_07_05_18_10_15_A9993E364706816ABA3E25717850C26C9CD0D89D_A81F008338868103F1A0DB69010279D55DB3751E.m`. And it's even possible to have several SHA1 hashes of different parameters sets in the same function name this way, eg. one defining the subjects to be included, other defining the data handling parameters etc., then concatenate both or all of them to the filename, and then compute SHA1 hash and write two identical functions as above.

Comment: Theoretically there still is a chance of hash collisions. So to be sure, you can add a check before writing out the function whether there already exists a file/function with the same name/hash and give the user a warning or retry writing the file a second later, hence with a different hash. By the way: eventually you'll run into the OS [filename limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) for your debug files :p But anyways: nice solution ;)

Comment: Checking for hash collisions is a good idea for stability, even if hash collisions would be extremely rare. Maximum filename length of 255 characters of ext4/ext3/ext2 etc. is quite enough for me, at least for now. For longer filenames, one option would be changing the file system to Reiser4, it has maximum filename length of 3976 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure that you cannot alter the limitation for the namelength.
But maybe you can omit the date in the 2nd timestamp. Instead of saving the full timestamp just use the offset (in the format 'HH:MM:SS' if the run needs x hours to finish; in the format 'dd HH:MM:SS' if the run needs x days to finish; ...).

Also you can look at

```
help datenum
```

in order to shorten your timestamps. But this function doesn't result in human-readable timestamps.

I now this is not very clever but it sounds to me like a problem with need for a very pragmatical solution.

Comment: by offset I mean the difference between the two timestamps

Comment: Leaving the date out saves some characters, as does compressing date into a not human-readable form, which I already mentioned. But these do not solve the fundamental problem of limited `namelengthmax` and thus do not permit my plan of incorporating hashes of parameter sets into the function name. See my own answer to myself.