# Why does Matlab only accept a small set of characters in script filenames?

Tags: matlab, special-characters, filenames

Matlab requires that script files are limited to only 63 characters

```
>> namelengthmax
ans =
    63
```

and these 63 characters must be out of a small characterset without `-` and others.

Why does Matlab limit the filenames and is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a definitive answer, but remember that script file names are also function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from *beaker* answers part of your question. Because they can also be funtion names, you are restricted in the character they can incorporate.

For example, if you had a file (function) named `foot-ball.m`, when you call it in an instruction, Matlab couldn't differentiate between:

```
a = foot-ball ;
```

where you mean to call the result of a function named `foot-ball.m` (actually impossible)

or

```
a = foot-ball ;
```

assigning to variable "a" the result of function `foot.m` minus the result of function `ball.m`

As to the maximum length, there are no workaround (yet) to my knowledge (until Matlab lift the restriction).

Remember that your operating system also has a limit to the length of file (and full path). On windows it is 256+4 characters. So I guess limiting a file name length to 63 is just to allow for 193 characters of full path. This can be quickly reached, faster than we think.

*If your filename was 255 character long, you would have no other choice than to put it directly into `c:\` or the operating system couldn't access it (so Matlab couldn't call it obviously).*

Use the instruction `len = namelengthmax` to get the actual maximum length on your system. You can read more about it in [specify file names](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/specify-file-names.html).

or also read a similar problem from another user: [Extending the maximum length of MATLAB function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348017/extending-the-maximum-length-of-matlab-function-names). Note that this user couldn't bypass the length limit, he had to find another way to fit all the information he wanted into the maximum file name.